# How to show an error message If user selects the wrong file type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am assigned a project, a part of which is to make the users select some files or a folder. My code is working fine. What I want to do is to raise an error message If the user selects a wrong file type. User should access a certain type of file when he/she clicks a certain button i.e If he clicks 'Select Java File/Folder' Button,then he/she will select only java files. Please guide. My code is below for selecting a file and a folder. What more do I need to add?

```
def Select_File(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='/', title='Select a File', 
                                               filetype=(('Java','*.java'),('C#','*.cs'),('C++','*.cpp')))
    if self.filename:
        self.scanner = FileScanner()
        self.data = self.scanner.Project_Scanner(self.filename)
        self.Display(self.data)
    else:
        self.msg.setText("No File Selected")
        self.msg.setInformativeText('Please Select a File to Proceed')
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
        self.msg.exec_()
 

def Select_Project(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    self.folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='/', title='Select Folder')
    if self.folder_selected:
        self.files = self.get_Files(self.folder_selected)
        self.scanner = FileScanner()
        self.data = self.scanner.Project_Scanner(self.files)
        self.Display(self.data)
    else:
        self.msg.setText("No Folder Selected")
        self.msg.setInformativeText('Please Select a Folder to Proceed')
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
        self.msg.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the other filetypes and checking the filename to see if it is a java file:

````py
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

def Select_File(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='/', title='Select a File', 
                                               filetype=(('Java','*.java'),))
    if self.filename:
        try:
            assert self.filename.split('.')[-1] == 'java'
            self.scanner = FileScanner()
            self.data = self.scanner.Project_Scanner(self.filename)
            self.Display(self.data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, type(e))
            showerror("File Open", "had an issue opening file")
    else:
        self.msg.setText("No File Selected")
        self.msg.setInformativeText('Please Select a File to Proceed')
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
        self.msg.exec_()```
````

Comment: I have 3 buttons for .java, .cs and .cpp files. Does that mean I need to create 3 seperate methods for each file extension?

Comment: @RabiSiddique can probably pass in which button is pressed, and then pass the tuple with the correct file extension type into `filetype`?

Comment: its working for selecting for files. But how can I do the same, when user selects a folder.

Comment: @RabiSiddique i think the assert would work for folders too for example `some/folder/java` wouldn't work and would raise an error? if you're iterating over the files in the folder, instead of raising an error on every single file, just ignore any files that don't pass the file ends with assertion.